# SKCanvas.DrawCircle() is drawing squares

Tags: c#, .net-core, opentk, skiasharp

I setup SkiaSharp in .NetCore using OpenGL. If I call the **DrawCircle()** function it renders squares, which seems weird. My code looks like this:

```
using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint {
    Style = SKPaintStyle.Stroke,
    Color = SKColors.Red,
    StrokeWidth = 25,
}) {
    canvas.RotateDegrees( 2 );
    canvas.DrawCircle( info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2, 100, paint );
    paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill;
    paint.Color = SKColors.Blue;
    canvas.DrawCircle( info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2, 75, paint );

    canvas.RotateDegrees( 20 );
    canvas.DrawCircle( info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2, 50, paint );
    paint.Style = SKPaintStyle.Fill;
    paint.Color = SKColors.Yellow;
    canvas.DrawCircle( info.Width / 2, info.Height / 2, 25, paint );

}
```

The screen then looks like this:
[image]

Why are there squares?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I accidentally fixed this issue by adding anti aliasing.

```
using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint {
     ...,
     ...,
     IsAntialias = true
}) {
     ...
}
```

[image]